# Not able to upload Dataset into AutoML Natural Language text classification GUI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-classification, automl

I'm trying to perform custom text classification by using AutoML on Google Cloud Platform. I am using the official google documentation to help me get started. The link to the blog is https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/no-deep-learning-experience-needed-build-a-text-classification-model-with-google-cloud-automl-natural-language

In the above above blog they have used the 20 Newsgroup dataset. After preparing the dataset and following the instructions given here I am getting an error while uploading the dataset into GCP AutoML Text Classification GUI.

I have also tried to upload a csv file with just one data entry that also doesn't seem to work.

Every time I try to upload dataset I get the following error

ERROR CODES:
4
Last error message
CSV file is empty

Answer (score 0):

More like a [csv issue](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare). If you use the [csv file](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/sample/happiness.csv) provided in the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/quickstart) then it will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cristopher! This dataset seems to work. [This](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/scikit-learn/20_newsgroups_automl.ipynb) is the dataset I am trying to use and its part of the official [google blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/no-deep-learning-experience-needed-build-a-text-classification-model-with-google-cloud-automl-natural-language). Can you help me understand what is wrong with the dataset? Thanks in advance :)